# How can I access /data/data directory of other app without rooting the phone

Tags: android

as per Google documentation,

> By default, files saved to the internal storage are private to your
>   application and other applications cannot access them (nor can the
>   user). When the user uninstalls your application, these files are
>   removed.

Source: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

**By default** implies that it is only temporary and can be modified. So is there any way to modify this permission to allow your app to read internal storage files from other Apps ?

I am willing to access `/data/data/com.Whatsapp` to access my encryption key to study how Whatsapp actually generates the key and i need to done this using my App, not a rooted phone or anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So is there any way to modify this permission to allow your app to read internal storage files from other Apps ?

No. In the quoted passage above, please see the "nor can the user" part. You, as a user, do not have rights to access those files, let alone change permissions on them. The exception is a user who roots their device.

Comment: It doesn't seem very user-friendly to design the OS in that way; wouldn't an OS be considered a better product without a built-in mechanism designed for the purpose of preventing the owner of the device from accessing something? I get wanting to protect it from other apps for privacy/security reasons, but in that case there should be a way for the user to give an app permission to do so. At the very least there should be some way for the user to do so directly. Giving the adb shell access to these files would be a perfect solution.